# Investment funds that make a difference

Tags: investing, ethical-investing

When searching for ethical investment funds, the usual model seems to be funds that exclude certain companies or sectors on environmental, social or governance reasons (ESG). I am, however, looking for funds that try to influence the companies they are invested in to act less evil (eg by voting accordingly in the shareholder meetings). Do these exist? If so, how do I find them? (eg, what are the right search terms, are there prominent comparison websites, etc)

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'Activist Shareholder', though I'm not aware of any that exist as public funds.

Comment: They most certainly exist, e.g.: https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/esg. Most of them though screen specific industries, rather than vote in certain ways.

Comment: @littleadv That's what I'm explicitly not looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I will keep it short
This is exactly what you are looking for.

https://ethicinvest.ca/shareholder-activism-and-proxy-voting/

These were the search words I would have given you. Great starting point. Most investment firms have guidelines for voting, but not all vote based on well-articulated ethical standards.

Other sources
https://blogs.cfainstitute.org/investor/2023/06/24/a-global-proxy-voting-database-an-idea-whose-time-has-come/

https://www.neiinvestments.com/responsible-investing/responsible-investing-expertise/reports/proxy-voting.html